# Using Wincache with Zend Framework 1.12.x

Tags: php, zend-framework, wincache

I'm trying to check if wincache is working properly in my zend framework 1.12 project and don't really get output by the wincache.php skript.

I'm on Windows 8 and Run IIS8 with PHP 5.3 and Wincache. phpinfo() shows wincache 1.3.4 is installed properly and working.

I also don't get any error messages or exceptions from Zend Framework telling it to use the backend 'Wincache'.

```
Zend_Cache::factory(
    'Core',
    'Wincache',
    array(
       'caching' => 1, 
       'lifetime' => '3600', 
       'automatic_serialization' => 1),
    array(
       'cache_dir' => 'C:\Projects\website\application\cache', 
       'file_locking' => 1, 
       'read_control' => 1, 
       'read_control_type' => 
       'adler32', 
       'ignore_user_abort' => 1));
```

Then I created a route and included the wincache.php script code in the view. But this shows no cache hits.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: problem was in the wincache.php script where globals defined did not work. Fixed the problem and it works now